# Why i get connection already closed?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I get connection already closed exception because of jdbc calls.

I close ressources like this:

```
catch (Exception ex) {
       conn.rollback();
       Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     } finally {
       if (cstmt != null) {
       cstmt.close();
      }
      conn.close();
     }
```

Comment: Which version of java you are using ?

Comment: Which line gives you that error? What are the operations you do with `conn` before that? Without a [mcve] or at least the full code that traces all uses of `conn` and all statements that are created from it, we can't say which statement closes it.

Comment: Connection conn = jdbcCallInterf.getConnection();
    CallableStatement cstmt = null;   cstmt = conn.prepareCall("begin ? := get_dos(?); end;");
      cstmt.setString(2, id);
      cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.ARRAY, arrayName.toUpperCase());Object[] data = (Object[]) ((Array) cstmt.getObject(1)).getArray();
      cstmt.execute();

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and the full exception stacktrace.